# Limiting position of point of intersection of lines

Tags: geometry, limits

The limiting position of the point of intersection of the straight lines 
$$3x+5y=1$$  and  $$(2+c)x+5c^2y=1$$ as $c \to 1$ is ?

a) $(2/5,-1/25)$
(b) $(1/2,-1/10)$
(c) $(3/8,-1/40)$
(d) none

I tried a lot this question but even didn't found my known lectures.
Please can any one help?

Comment: How did you narrow it down to just these four possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the first equation we get
$$x=\frac{1-5y}{3}$$ plugging this in the second equation we have
$$y(5c^2-\frac{5}{3}(2+c))=1-\frac{2+c}{3}$$ thus $$y=\frac{1-c}{15c^2-5c-10}$$
since $$15c^2-5c-10=5(3c+2)(c-1)$$ we get
$$\lim_{c\to 1}\frac{1-c}{5(3c+2)(c-1)}=-\frac{1}{25}$$